# Convert Triangle Wave to Sine Wave

Tags: wave

I have this triangle wave as input:

[image: Input]

and I want to derive a sine wave out of it. How do I go about it?

PS: I am doing this in Lua, so any piece of code close to that language would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you take a drawing program and show us what kind of output you expect for this particular input? When the waveform abruptly goes back to zero, do you consider this as a rapid frequency increase - and thus, do you expect your sine wave to rapidly move through zero?

Comment: I'm trying to make that wave smoother by transforming it to a sine wave. I'm expecting same zero-crossing points, same extreme level points but with the smooth of a sine wave. Any mathematical operation to do this?

Comment: Yes, multiplying by pi and taking the sin will do the trick. Same extrema, same zero-crossings.

Comment: y[x] = sin(pi * h[x]) ?
where y[x] is the output at sample x and h[x] the input

Comment: @pichenettes It's not working properly, as you can see in this input/output picture: http://hpics.li/9de5a96

Comment: Sorry, I meant pi/2...

Comment: Alternatively you could also find an interpolant through the zero crossings and the maxima. This will give you additional continuity in the derivatives and might be preferable depending on what you need this for.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac could you detail that procedure please? I do not come from a mathematical background so a simple explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: Interpolation is a rather complex topic and nothing that I could thoroughly explain in a comment or even a full grown answer. However you can find libraries that perform the most common interpolation tasks for most languages. You want something like spline interpolation, as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x(t)$ swings between -1 and 1, $\sin \frac{\pi}{2} x(t)$ might do the trick.